# Is is possible to split a generic type?

Tags: typescript

API endpoints that I call deliver data in the following shapes:

```
interface ArrayResponse<T> {
   data: Partial<T>[]
}
```

```
interface ObjectResponse<T> {
   data: Partial<T>
}
```

I've written a function that calls endpoints and returns responses:

```
function fetchOne<T>(path: string): ObjectResponse<T> {
  // HTTP call
}

function fetchMany<T>(path: string): ArrayResponse<T> {
  // Exact same HTTP logic as above
}
```

Ideally I want to have a single response type:

```
interface Response<T> {
  data: Partial<T> | Partial<T>[]
}
```

But I what I really want is to be able to have the above type to determine Partial or Partial[] based on the value passed for T.

So `Response<T>` would result in `data: Partial<T>` and `Response<T>[]` results in `data: Partial<T>[]`.

I'm also open to other creative ways of achieving the same effect.

Comment: In your question you write `Response<T>[]`, however `fetchMany` returns a single response.

Comment: `fetchMany` returns an `ArrayResponse<T>` which includes a `data: Partial<T>[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done. But regardless of how you set this up you would need to manually set the generic `T` when calling, like `fetch<MyType>(path)`, in order to get a meaningful response type because the generic `T` cannot possibly be inferred from the path which is a string.

Try this:

```
function fetchEither<T>(path: string): T extends (infer U)[] ? ArrayResponse<U> : ObjectResponse<T> {   
}
```

With this setup, you would pass in `MyType` as `T` to get a single response or `MyType[]` as `T` for a multiple response. (note: this assumes that `MyType` itself would not be an array)

```
const array = fetchEither<MyType[]>(""); // has type ArrayResponse<MyType>
const object = fetchEither<MyType>(""); // has type ObjectResponse<MyType>
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIJSnAngJQgZwAcB7EfCAHgBUA%20ZAbwFgAoZNgEzjDgC5kAFOFDDA4AG2o0A2gF0WAXxahIsRCgDyAIwBWEBGDxFS5SQxZtknbn0HDRE2gpbPmMAK4h9wUshgQwCAAW6iCUtAAUhFyBfPhgUKAA5gCUfFq6%20oYkZGF0TKzIAPSFyAASVFT8yAjiYk7MLO6eIj5%20AYEAsnAgWJKR0bHxSaloGNhZxrlmBcXIAKIAHohgyPhwALYo5ZXIYsSJwAjIcPjHmsQAbhD1SuDQ8EjIHVhUWIQo%20RbIANYQWHwAIgu4jcEABN1cHi8rX8QTmwDAgWgfSiiMGCRAKT4VGQEAWkBA7FO4VAfigyAAqslZMgAPyjTC4AjZEwUuhpHR6AzMyamfIQhDGFZCRl8dCMiY5CjPV7vOgAXl8sMC8MRyJlbwgsho4QBAOSAG4WIKyCtiJz9ByMtyjFKNXLkIq2nCEUioNKXpqdXrDUA)

Given that `T` cannot be inferred, it might make more sense to just return a union type and determine the value at runtime as proposed by @Thatkookooguy.

Comment: wow! very different but very cool methods are coming up in these answers! loving this discussion! :-)

Comment: This is brilliant. I actually don't need it to infer the type since I always know when I make the call what's being returned (this is for an API endpoint).

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using [User-Defined Type Guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)

so, if you have these interfaces:

```typescript
interface ObjectResponse<T> {
  data: Partial<T>
}

interface ArrayResponse<T> {
  data: Partial<T>[]
}

type IResponse<T> = ObjectResponse<T> | ArrayResponse<T>;
```

You can write this guard function:

```typescript
function isMultiResponse<T>(response: IResponse<T>): response is ArrayResponse<T> {
  return Array.isArray(response.data);
}
```

This function will get a type of `IResponse<T>`, and determines if it's an `ArrayResponse<T>`. This will allow you to check at runtime what kind of type it is.

This translates to regular javascript, but typescript knows that this function determines the type.

So, for your two functions, you can combine them if the logic is the same:

```typescript
async function fetchData<T>(path: string): Promise<IResponse<T>> {
  // HTTP call
  return get(path);
}
```

And when you use the user defined guard function, typescript will know which type the response is:

```typescript
async function doSomething<T>(): Promise<void> {
  const path = '';
  const res: IResponse<T> = await fetchData(path);

  if (isMultiResponse(res)) {
    // typescript will know the response is ArrayResponse<T>
    console.log(res.data[0]);
  } else {
    // typescript will know the response is ObjectResponse<T>
    console.log(res.data);
  }
}
```

### VS Code in action

---

the first type is `Partial<T>[]` as expected
[image: vscode detects this as a T[]]

---

the second type is `Partial<T>` as expected
[image: vscode detects this as T]

### Compiled code

When compiled to JavaScript, the `isMultiResponse` function and if statement will obviously be there. But you probably want a check like that somewhere in your code anyway :-) Writing it using a [Type Guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) will do the necessary check at runtime, **but will also make typescript aware of the two different scenarios and give you feedback accordingly**.

Comment: This is very similar to what my code already does. The issue is that I'm trying to avoid doing type checks in cases where I already know that the response is going to return an Array.

Comment: If you already know the response is an array, and the function you're in will NEVER get another value, just use `ArrayResponse<T>`. If sometimes gets an array and sometimes isn't, use the multi-response with the type checks. That what you would have done regardless of Typescript types. Another approach that I like is converting all responses to the same format. So, whatever you get, you always make sure it's an array wrapping a response (single response is an array of length 1, while array response is an array of length >=1). This way, you don't need any type checks after the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone else can think outside the box better than I, but what you're asking for doesn't seem possible. Posting this answer for the sake of discussion. Let's try a simpler example. What you have right now:

```
function returnString(): string {
  // returns string
}

function returnNumber(): number {
  // returns number
}

let string: string = returnString();
let number: number = returnNumber();
```

Now let's say you try to add a union type. Notice that regardless of what happens inside your function at runtime, the compiler can't infer the appropriate type:

```
type StringOrNumber = string | number;

function returnString(): StringOrNumber {
  // returns string
}

function returnNumber(): StringOrNumber {
  // returns number
}

let string: string = returnString();
// Type 'StringOrNumber' is not assignable to type 'string'.
//  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.

let number: number = returnNumber();
// Type 'StringOrNumber' is not assignable to type 'number'.
//  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Comment: Checkout my answer! It should solve your example as well!

Comment: Look into [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).  `function returnStringOrNumber<T extends string | number>(): T` will do it, with the caveat that `T` would need to be set manually if there are no args from which it can be inferred. `function returnStringOrNumber<T extends string | number>(input: T): T` where the input type matches the output type is the easiest.